# Allow remote RPC to Ethereum parity node

Tags: parity

I have a fully synchronized Parity Ethereum node running on Ubuntu 16
I tried to find a straight answer on how to enable the node to accepts remote RPC calls from a specific client but could not find any. 
I use the following command:

```
parity --mode active --tracing off --pruning fast --db-compaction ssd --cache-size 1024
```

Also, I would really like to know how to run it in the background, as now I have to connect via SSH and keep the connection running.
Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://wiki.parity.io/Configuring-Parity-Ethereum), you must simply add:

`--jsonrpc-apis=[APIS]`

where [APIs] is a comma-delimited list of API names. Possible names are: all, safe, debug, web3, net, eth, pubsub, personal, signer, parity, parity_pubsub, parity_accounts, parity_set, traces, rpc, secretstore, shh, shh_pubsub. You can also disable a specific API by putting '-' in the front, example: all,-personal.

Comment: doc link is dead